# Create Social Graph Dataset From Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I am doing a project at my college and I want to build a social graph from Facebook.

I want only the connections between users (friendship) so I can build a Graph.
I read the Facebook API documentation, from my understanding it doesn't allow to fetch my friends' friends, meaning that I'm stuck at first depth.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Without using a crawler, which is most likely against the TOS, this is not possible.

You could use the first depth to make only a first degree connection graph based on mutual friends within your friend network.

```
/userid1/friends/userid2
```

It would be easier to center your project around Twitter's data.